# 13.04 to 13.10 upgrade stalled at flashplugin-installer

Tags: installation, 13.04, upgrade, 13.10

13.04 to 13.10 upgrade stalled at flashplugin-installer some 5+ hours
unsure how to proceed?
is there any way to skip this and move to the next step .. and deal with the flashpugin later?

Comment: You can try installing restricted-extras later?

Comment: Try removing it so it won't update, then install it again after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found:
1. boot to 13.10 live CD
2. ran install upgrade
3. choose to complete failed upgrade

side complication was problem with DVD player reading/coping the install .. patvhed in replacement USB DVD player.

.. all worked well and completed install booted correctly. 
Found that couple of previously installed application missing.. eg: Chromium, Cheese, and  a few other have re-added.
All working well since.
Found the advice on Askubuntu very helpful if not directly leading to a solution